# Is there any way to turn simple matrix to graph?

Tags: c++, matrix, graph, kruskals-algorithm, prims-algorithm

For example, I have a matrix like this;

> 1 2 3 4
>   2 4 5 1
>   1 2 4 1
>   5 3 2 1

and I select 3 nodes from this matrix as random. How can I make graph from these nodes? Is there any algorithm or way to make this happen? I know how to make adjacency matrix from graph but I just can't make the graph from the random matrix right now.

EDIT:

For example, I select row:1 col:1 as first node and row:3 col:1 as second node, it should find the shortest way between first node and second node and make graph of them.

Comment: what does it mean to "select a node from this matrix"?  do the cells in the matrix represent node names?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this 4x4 matrix represents the adjacency matrix from a graph with 4 nodes.  In this case, taking 3 nodes randomly, would mean to select 3 random lines and take the corresponding columns, and you have a reduced graph defined by its adjacency list.

EDIT:

According  to your edit, each of the 16 matrix item would be a node uniquely identified by its coordinates (i,j). Each of these nodes would be connected at least to his 2 to 4 neighbors. Then some clarifications are needed:

- is the value of the item just the label of on of the 16 nodes ?
- are the only moves vertical and horitontal or are diagonal allowed ?
- are moves bound by the borders or can thy flip over (i.e. The last item of a row is connected with the first) ?
- are the cost of each move from one to the next equal or is the cost of each move related to the values of the node traversed ?

You can then easily build the 16*16 ajacency matrix for the 16 items and apply the method of the shortest path.

Comment: I edited the question. The problem is that is not an adjacency matrix. I just can't make the adjacency matrix from that matrix with nodes I choose.